# python image sequence loop issue

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a script that checks for image sequences within a list of files. So far it's running fairly well, but for some reason it always skips the first file of every new sequence. This is my code so far:

```
import os, re
filelist = ["A01B02_0123_A333.01234321.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234322.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234323.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234324.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234325.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234326.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234327.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234328.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234329.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234330.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234331.ari", "A02B03_0123_A444.0052.ari", "bus_v01.1001.tif", "bus_v01.1002.tif", "bus_v01.1003.tif", "bus_v02.1001.tif", "bus_v02.1002.tif", "bus_v02.1003.tif", "elementA_1001.jpg", "elementA_1002.jpg", "elementA_1003.jpg", "elementB_1001.jpg", "elementB_1002.jpg", "elementB_1003.jpg"]

def digitgroups(file):
    padding_expr = re.compile("\d+")
    lastfile = ""
    sequence_index = 0

    for file in filelist:

        if file.endswith((".dpx", ".ari", ".jpg", ".tif")):
            match = re.findall(padding_expr, file)[::-1]
            lastmatch = re.findall(padding_expr, lastfile)[::-1]

            if len(match) == len (lastmatch) and file != lastfile:

                for i in range (0, len(match)):
                    digit_difference = int(lastmatch[i])-int(match[i])

                    if not (digit_difference) == 0:

                        if digit_difference == -1 or digit_difference == 1 and os.path.splitext(file)[-1] is os.path.splitext(l)[-1]:
                            print file, "a is part of sequence {0}".format(sequence_index)
                        elif digit_difference < -1 or digit_difference > 1:
                            sequence_index += 1

                        break

            lastfile = file

digitgroups(filelist)
```

Comment: try to code block your code so we can actaully read.

Comment: `is` compares object identity whereas `==` compares object value. You want `file != lastfile`.

Comment: `list` is a builtin type and you are overriding it. That's bad practice.

Comment: @Ale `list` is a type, but yes, it's a built-in and shouldn't be used as a name.

Comment: I have no idea what this code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you for your input, I changed my code accordingly but the problem remains.

@msw: I am trying to split a list of files (filelist) into a list of (image)sequences by checking for digit sequences in the filename. An imagesequence will have consecutive numbering at the end of the file so that's what I'm looking for (within all files that are images -> ".ari", ".tif" etc.). Then I start looking for other differences in the matched digit patterns that will resemble versioning, shot numbering, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from everything mentioned in the comments, the loop is dependent on `lastfile` being not blank.

On the first pass:

```
if len(match) == len (lastmatch) and file is not lastfile:
```

will not be true on the first pass, because lastfile was set to `""` and `len(lastmatch)` will be `0`.

Also, you're passing `list` in and then calling if `file` in the function.
The solution below worked for me (EDITED, more complete solution):

```
import os, re
mylist = ["A01B02_0123_A333.01234321.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234322.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234323.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234324.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234325.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234326.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234327.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234328.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234329.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234330.ari", "A01B02_0123_A333.01234331.ari", "A02B03_0123_A444.0052.ari", "bus_v01.1001.tif", "bus_v01.1002.tif", "bus_v01.1003.tif", "bus_v02.1001.tif", "bus_v02.1002.tif", "bus_v02.1003.tif", "elementA_1001.jpg", "elementA_1002.jpg", "elementA_1003.jpg", "elementB_1001.jpg", "elementB_1002.jpg", "elementB_1003.jpg"]

def digitgroups(files):
    padding_expr = re.compile("\d+")
    lastfile = ""
    sequence_index = 0

    for f in files:
        if f.endswith((".dpx", ".ari", ".jpg", ".tif")):
            match = re.findall(padding_expr, f)[::-1]
            lastmatch = re.findall(padding_expr, lastfile)[::-1]

            if len(match) == len(lastmatch) and f is not lastfile:
                for i in range (0, len(match)):
                    digit_difference = int(lastmatch[i])-int(match[i])
                    if not digit_difference == 0:
                        if digit_difference == -1 or digit_difference == 1 and os.path.splitext(f)[-1] is os.path.splitext(l)[-1]:
                            print(f, "a is part of sequence {0}".format(sequence_index))
                        elif digit_difference < -1 or digit_difference > 1:
                            sequence_index += 1

                        break
            else:
                print(f, "a is part of sequence {0}".format(sequence_index))
            lastfile = f

digitgroups(mylist)
```

Notice the `lastfile = files.pop(0)`. This gets the first element from the `files` list.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This solves part of my problem -> not only is the first file from my list dropped, this happens to every first file of a new sequence; eg. "elementB_1001.jpg", "bus_v01.1001.tif", etc.

Comment: That is because of that `if len(match) == len(lastmatch)...` line again. It will most likely be false for every sequence change. So the first file in the sequence doesn't get printed and then that file gets put in as the `lastfile` and the rest of the sequence matches.

Comment: I think you want to look at adding an `else` to the `if`. If it doesn't match than assume it is the first one in the sequence. Or something like that

Comment: see the edited solution, seems to work like you explained

Comment: yes, this works indeed as expected! "elementB_1001.jpg" and "A02B03_0123_A444.0052.ari" are not printed so I will have to adjust my loops a bit, but you pointed me in the right direction - thank you!